# React.js Props turns undefined after refresh

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, undefined, react-props

I am pulling a huge list of 1000+ keywords from a firebase database and passing it down from App.js down to a component that creates an autocomplete search bar. The props are passes perfectly at first. I have even done a "console.log(props.keywords[30].keyword);" and I get one specific keyword that shows up exactly the way I would like in the console. Later in the code of the keywords component, I try to reference keyword again, but when I refresh the page to make sure everything works, it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyword' of undefined". It was working before I hit refresh on the browser. I am just trying to make it so that I can pull a few keywords that a user has predefined and set them as userOptions to be chips as the page loads, and then the user can choose more keywords if needed or delete the one they have predefined. But out of nowhere somehow it gets undefined. Thanks in advance.

More of the error from Chrome:

```
  17 | function Keywords(props) {
  18 |  const classes = useStyles();
  19 | 
> 20 |  console.log(props.keywords[30].keyword);
  21 | 
  22 |  //const allOptions = [props.keywords[6]];
  23 |  const userOptions = [props.keywords[6]];
```

Here is the full code for the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        '& > * + *': {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
        },
        paddingBottom: '8px',
    },
}));

function Keywords(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    console.log(props.keywords[30].keyword);

    //const allOptions = [props.keywords[6]];
    const userOptions = [props.keywords[6]];
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState([...userOptions, props.keywords[13]]);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="fixed-tags-demo"
                value={value}
                onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                    setValue([...newValue]);
                }}
                options={props.keywords}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.keyword}
                freeSolo
                renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) => tagValue.map((option, index) => <Chip label={option.keyword} {...getTagProps({ index })} />)}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Keywords" placeholder="Roles, Locations, Etc." />}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Keywords;
```

Comment: I can just guess here, as you have not provided the code of the parent component but I guess that the `Keywords` component will not have the full list of items available in its first render, perhaps as the data is still loading. But that depends on how you actually invoice the Component. Please consider sharing the parent component's code.

Comment: You are right. I figured out that the data is still loading and in refreshing the page, the full list isn't defined at that time. I need to figure out a way to put an async to it. I am still learning how this works.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `props && yourLogic...` or any other type of safe guarding for props react has this problem of not having props available on the first render sometimes (IMHO)

Comment: This is how it looks from App.js:  const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState([]);

 const getKeywords = () => {
  db.collection('keywords')
   .orderBy('slug', 'asc')
   .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    setKeywords(
     snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      return {
       keyword: doc.data().keyword,
       slug: doc.data().slug,
      };
     })
    );
   });
 };

 useEffect(() => {
  getShifts();
  getKeywords();
 }, []);

Then I pass keywords={keywords} in calling the component.
I need to figure out how to do this async.

Comment: if you try `console.log(props.keywords[0]);` do you get the same error?

Comment: At first I do, then the page loads more and then the console.log runs again and the data is correct.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge something like this should work:

` 
if(props.keywords){

console.log(props.keywords[30].keyword);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment:

The data is not fully loaded on the first render of the `Keywords` component. The react way of handling this is to either build an early return in your component and return null, so that nothing is rendered or to use a hook like `useMemo` in order to compute `value? . You can pass a dependency array to` useMemo` and it will recompute the function whenever a dependency changes.

I think using a hook is the way to go for you in this case. Inside it, you can then handle the case in which the data is not loaded yet and instead return some safe default value.

Answer (score 0):

for me the answer was also looking into loading and adding a extra conditional for arrayObj  and adding that in my isLoading spinner conditional. react has something on this that explains better than I could but this post lead me to look into this and it worked. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator